# Android handler.postDelayed() speeds up with every iteration

Tags: java, android, android-handler

I have such handler:

```
    public void changeSpinnerWaitSelection2() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (count <= 3) spinnerWait.setSelection(count, true);
            count++;
            mTimerHandler2.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
   }
```

which speeds up with every iteration. Variable `count` is reset in another place. What's wrong with this handler?

Whereas another method that does the same works perfectly:

```
public void changeSpinnerWaitSelection() {
    TimerTask mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mTimerHandler5.post(() -> {
                if (count > 4) { mTimer2.cancel();}
                if (count <= 3) spinnerWait.setSelection(count, true);
                count++;
            });
        }
    };
    mTimer2 = new Timer();
    mTimer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(mTt1, 0, 500);
}
```

But I would prefer first version due to lack TimerTask which seems to be harmfull to one of my devices.

Comment: I will suggest use Thread.sleep rather than TimerHandler

Comment: With thread sleep it does not work at all I mean this spinner selection is not called.

Comment: Then dont call this method on main UI thread declare asycn method for that it will easily be done there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First variant hasnt exit and run infinitely and possibly duplicated

Try

```
if (count <= 3) spinnerWait.setSelection(count, true);
            count++;
            mTimerHandler2.postDelayed(this, 500);
```

replace to

```
if (count <= 3) {
            spinnerWait.setSelection(count, true);
            count++;
            mTimerHandler2.postDelayed(this, 500);
}
```